# Why ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file (inside server) that calls a python script (inside server) to unzip and that calls another batch (inside server) with popen. The issue is related to the fact that each time i call the batch the file are unzipped but the second batch is not called. I think because of the error message in the title. However if I try to run everything on my pc, instead of locating those files within server everything works
Thank you for the attention

Comment: Does the python script call the second batch file? or does the first batch file call it after having run the python script? Your question suggests the former, which means we may need to see the content of the python script as well as the content of the first batch file.

Comment: \\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\SCRIPT_AND_BATCHES\SSC_Files_AUTOMATION'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.